# Elasticsearch sum total values for specific hours within a month

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch server with fields: `timestamp`, `user` and `bytes_down` (among others)

I would like to total the bytes_down value for a user for a month BUT only where the hours are between 8am and 8pm

I'm able to get the daily totals with the date histogram with following query (I'm using the perl API here) but can't figure out a way of reducing this down to the hour range for each day

```php
my $query = {
index => 'cm',
    body  => {
        query => {
            filtered => {
                query => {
                    term => {user => $user}
                },
                filter => {
                    and => [
                    {
                        range => {
                            timestamp => {
                                gte => '2014-01-01',
                                lte => '2014-01-31'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        bool => {
                            must => {
                                term => { zone => $zone }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        facets => {
            bytes_down => {
                date_histogram => {
                    field => 'timestamp',
                    interval => 'day',
                    value_field => 'downstream'
                }
            }
        },
        size => 0
    }
};
```

Thanks
Dale

Comment: I hope my answer helped, give me any question you have.

Comment: Are you using a 1.x or 90.x series of Elasticsearch?

Comment: Michael I'm using 1.x

Comment: Are you using facets instead of aggregations for any particular reason?

Comment: Hi Michael. No real reason. Would Agg's be a better way to go? do you have an example of how to accomplish this with aggregations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use [`script`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-filter.html) filter instead of `range` filter and then you need to put it in `facet_filter` section of your facet:

```php
"facet_filter" => {
    "script" => {
        "script" => "doc['timestamp'].date.getHourOfDay() >= 8 &&
                     doc['timestamp'].date.getHourOfDay() < 20"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a bool must range filter for every hour, I'm not sure if you're looking to do this forever or for the specific day, but this slide show from Zachary Tong is a good way to understand what you could be doing, especially with filters in general.
https://speakerdeck.com/polyfractal/elasticsearch-query-optimization?slide=28